# Reg: Socket Connection in Ionic3

Tags: socket.io, ionic2, ionic3

I am having an issue with the `socket` connection with my ionic3 application. I am using `socket` for implementing chat. Please find the below work flow.

1. I have configured the `socket.io` in my dashboard moudule (Not on `app.module.ts`) because I have to pass user token while connection which is obtained only after login. I have added screenshot below. Here I am getting success socket connection with the server. 
   [image]

   2. When I import the socket in my chat page, I am getting the below error.

   [image]

Is there any mistake in my approach? If my question is not clear to you please comment below before downvoting.

Comment: have u try with adding "SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)" in app.module.ts file also?